# Instantiating ActiveX Controls in a worksheet using vba

Tags: excel, vba, activexobject

I am trying to create a tool in Excel. My first problem is that I cannot reliably instantiate labels and textboxes on my worksheet. I currently have the code below.

```
Sub Test2()
Dim Schedule As Worksheet
Set Schedule = Worksheets("Schedule")

'Creates the row number
Schedule.OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.Label.1"
With Worksheets("Schedule").Label1
.Caption = 1
.width = 18
.Height = 18
.Top = 0
.Left = 0
.SpecialEffect = 1
.BackColor = &H8000000F
.TextAlign = 2
End With

End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Test3()
Dim Schedule As Worksheet
Set Schedule = Worksheets("Schedule")

Schedule.OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1"

With Worksheets("Schedule").TextBox1
.Text = "Task Name"
.width = 200
.Height = 18
.Top = 0
.Left = 18
.SpecialEffect = 0
.BackColor = &H80000005
.TextAlign = 1
.BorderStyle = 1
End With

End Sub
```

These both work on their own, but when you run one then the other an error is generated

> "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method".

Any advice?

Also, how would I store and access these labels and text boxes if I have an indefinite amount being created, I assume some sort of collect?

Comment: At what line does the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

For some of the properties, you'll need to refer to the Object property of the OleoObject object...

```
Sub Test2()

    'Creates the row number
    With Worksheets("Schedule").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1")
        .Left = 0
        .Top = 0
        .Width = 18
        .Height = 18
        With .Object
            .Caption = 1
            .SpecialEffect = 1
            .BackColor = &H8000000F
            .TextAlign = 2
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Test3()

    With Worksheets("Schedule").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1")
        .Left = 18
        .Top = 0
        .Width = 200
        .Height = 18
        With .Object
            .Text = "Task Name"
            .SpecialEffect = 0
            .BackColor = &H80000005
            .TextAlign = 1
            .BorderStyle = 1
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!